# Google Apps Script dataValidation code not working

Tags: validation, google-apps-script

Could you please help get the dataValidation part of the code working? All the other parts of the code is working, only the dataValidation part is not working unfortunately.

**Here is the code:**
// "Ready Line" formats word in column J

```
     if (r.getColumn() == 10 && e.value == "A Ready Line") {
      sheet.getRange(r.getRow(),r.getColumn()).setBackgroundColor("#FFFF00");
      sheet.getRange(r.getRow(),r.getColumn()).setFontColor("#38761d");
      var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(['B Hold', 'C Confirm']).build();
      sheet.getRange(r.getRow(),r.getColumn()).setDataValidation(rule);
   // Timestamp column CG  
      sheet.getRange(r.getRow(),r.getColumn()+75).setValue(new Date());
   // Clear columns MtoAA,   
      sheet.getRange(r.getRow(),r.getColumn()+3,1,15).clearContent();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use requireValueInList instead of requireValueInRange:

```
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['B Hold', 'C Confirm']).build();
```

Also setBackgroundColor is depreciated.  As well you can simplify your code by using this:

```
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['B Hold', 'C Confirm']).build();

sheet.getRange(r.getRow(),r.getColumn())
  .setBackground("#FFFF00")
  .setFontColor("#38761d")
  .setDataValidation(rule);
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.